# How to export complete stack in text file using wpaexporter (Windows Performance Toolkit)

Tags: window, xperf

How to export complete stack in text file using `"Windows Performance Toolkit"` utility `wpaexporter`. I am using this command but this give only the root element not complete stack.

```
C:\>wpaexporter.exe -i C:\data\test.etl -profile C:\data\cpu.wpaProfile -outputfolder C:\data -symbols -tti
```

Answer (score 1):

In WPA, "flatten" the table, so that all fields are in the middle (after the golden bar and before the blue bar), then save it as a profile.